# start an application on Boot

Tags: android

There are tons of questions on *Stackoverflow*  about starting an app on boot.
I wen over all of them, Searched for google but it just doesn't work.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

<receiver
        android:name=".BootUpReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

**BootUpReceiver**

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.w(TAG, "onReceive: starting app");
    Intent i = new Intent(context, Launcher.class);
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(i);
}
```

**Relevant logs on boot:**

```
D/PackageManager: PROCAPK:/data/app/com.example.app-1  pkg name:com.example.app
W/PackageManager: Failure retrieving resources for com.example.app: Resource ID #0x0
AppOps: check op 53 uid 10109 for com.example.app

**BroadcastQueue: App ops not allowed for broadcast to uid 10109 pkg com.example.app**

D/BroadcastQueue: processNextBroadcast app ops skip = true, action = android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED, package = com.example.app

I/LMS: find package:com.example.app, cert idx :19
                                 pkg key: long string
```

**EDIT**

This code works on an emulator. I guess it does depends on the device securities...Any ideas?

Comment: 1) Do you have the permission listed outside of the `<application>` tags in the manifest? 2) If running on Android 3.1+, are you running an `Activity` in your app at least once after installation, before rebooting, to bring it out of the _stopped_ state? 3) You should remove the `permission` attribute from the `<receiver>` element, as that specifies a permission that the sender must have, not the permission that your app needs.

Comment: Remove <category ..../> in manifest and try again

Comment: @MikeM. thanks. 1. permission listed outside. 2 ran, closed the app and ran again, then booted, 3. removed it and tried without...not working.

Comment: @Akash thanks. tried without category..didn't work. also is there a reason to move it?

Comment: What kind of device are you running on? Some OEMs, like Xiaomi, have additional settings/permissions that restrict apps running at startup, in the background, etc. Have a look the the device's Settings.

Comment: lenovo tab2..It's the first thing i did...Didn't find anything special in Settings

Comment: OK, it looks like it might not be in the Settings. Do you have a separate Security app somewhere?

Comment: None )-: mcAfee is bloated but not activated...I can't see any other program that will prevent BootUp

Comment: Dunno. You might try uninstalling, clean/rebuild, reinstall. Other than that, I can't think of what else to suggest, atm.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have an app installed called Security HD? Just wanted to double check, 'cause it's even discussed on Lenovo's site for their Tab 2.

Comment: @MikeM. Sadly no...(-: